# Filter moongose results by reference field using express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I need filter the products of a collection by category id which is a reference field.

product.js

```
const restful = require('node-restful')
const mongoose = restful.mongoose

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  category: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CategoryProduct'}
})

productSchema.pre('find', function () {
  this.find().populate('category')
})

module.exports = restful.model('product', productSchema)
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const auth = require('./auth')
module.exports = function (server) {
  const protectedApi = express.Router()
  server.use('/api', protectedApi)
  const Product = require('../api/product/productService')
  Product.register(protectedApi, '/products')
}
```

If I run this on Postman, `http://localhost:3003/api/products/?name__regex=/test/i`, I can get all products which contains 'test' on name.

So I try get all products by a specific category doing this, `http://localhost:3003/api/products/?category=5af3ac4372edc6000468d766`.
But as the category is an objectID, I receive this error:

```
{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5\" at path \"category\" for model \"SimpleProduct\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "stringValue": "\"5\"",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": 5,
    "path": "category"
}
```

How do I filter the products by category? I do not know how to treat this parameter correctly and pass to mongoose

---

Here is my CategoryProduct.js file

```
const restful = require('node-restful')

const mongoose = restful.mongoose

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: 'O campo Categoria é obrigatório'},
  status: {type: Number, required: true},
  updated_at: {type: Date}
})

module.exports = restful.model('CategoryProduct', categorySchema)
```

Comment: you can use the mongoose types. `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('req.query.category');`

Comment: @SunnyGohil, where can I do this? In express or in product.js? If you have an example, I appreciate it.

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have to do the following in your route:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
   const category = req.query.category; // assign the query param for use

   // mongoose query now
   Product.find({category: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category)}, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {console.log(err)};
      if (result) {
         res.json(result);
      }
   });
});
```

This is just a basic example. Since you are using node-restful you might have to adjust the code but the main idea here is that you require the mongoose module using

`const mongoose = require('mongoose')`

then pass your category query param to it to convert the string to objectID using:

`mongoose.Types.ObjectID(YOUR_CATEGORY_PARAM_HERE)`

You can do this anywhere, in the your routes.js or in your express.js, just have to have the string you want to convert :)

hope that helps :).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply @SunnyGohil.
I put the route in my routes.js and if I pass find () using an empty object I get all the products. But when I try to filter by category, I always get an empty return.

Comment: I forgot to tell, filter by name works too, just category won't.

Comment: what does you 'CategoryProduct' schema look like? can you include that code aswell?. The category id you are passing definetly exists in the database right? and there is no typos or whatever when your passing the id?

Comment: Added! Yes, the ID exist, and I tried with more that one. No, I copy the ID direct from the return and just paste.